# const value as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I just run into a compile error from both gcc and clang, so I assume this code is not possible :

```
template < typename T >
struct Type {

  using type = T;
};

template < int size = 1024 >
struct Foo {};

constexpr auto test_ = [] (const int size) {

  return Type<Foo<size>>;
};
```

**Compile error :**

```
test.cpp:12:19: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
  return Type<Foo<size>>;
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

The question is why? `size` is a const value and should be able to fit as a template parameter no? I already used some static const value as template parameter, but seems this case is not supported.

Comment: The problem is that `size` is not a compile time value, you could potentially call that lambda with a value coming from a command-line argument.

Comment: If a variable is `const`, it, doesn't, necessarily mean that it is known at compile time (as is needed for template arguments). Imagine this sort of example: `int a; std::cin >> a; const int b = a;`. `b` is `const`, but the value of it is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `size` is a const value and should be able to fit as a template parameter no?

No, `const` values are not necessarily known at compile-time *(i.e. they're not **constant expressions**)*.

What you want is [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant):

```
constexpr auto test_ = [] (auto size) 
{
    return Type<Foo<size>>{};
};

test_(std::integral_constant<int, 100>{});
```

---

As [Rakete1111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3980929/rakete1111) mentioned in the comments, the line `return Type<Foo<size>>;` is also ill-formed - you probably wanted to instantiate it as I did above.

Comment: You might want to add that `Type<Foo<size>>` is a type, and as such, you can't return it. You have to create an instance of it, or use `::type`

Comment: Oh right sorry, I changed it from hana::type_c and forgot the init. Thanks :)