# Can trivial integral const variables always be used as template values?

Tags: c++, templates

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659475/const-value-as-template-parameter), but more specific to pre-c++11 scenarios.

I've noticed with Clang and g++ that the following compiles and works fine with pre-c++11:

```cpp
enum En { V0 = 0 };

template <int SZ> class C { };
template <En EN> class E { };

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 42;
    C<SIZE> c;
    const int SIZE2 = SIZE ^ 0xDEADBEEF;
    C<SIZE2> c2;
    const En E1 = V0;
    E<E1> e1;
}
```

In a context where no `constexpr` is available, doing this is incredibly convenient, perhaps even necessary in some cases. So is this guaranteed to work, or are g++ and Clang just inferring these values for convenience?

Comment: See [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). `SIZE` and `E1` are constant expressions, their values are clearly known at compile time, so this is allowed. This predates C++11.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Integral Constant Expressions, even, to use the C++98 term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is this guaranteed to work

Yes. From [expr.const]/1 in [N1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) (which is C++03-ish standard release):

> #### 5.19 Constant expressions [expr.const]
>
> /1 In several places, C++ requires **expressions that evaluate to an
> integral or enumeration constant**: as array bounds (8.3.4, 5.3.4),
> as case expressions (6.4.2), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator
> initializers (7.2), as static member initializers (9.4.2), and **as
> integral or enumeration non-type template arguments** (14.3).
>
> An *integral constant-expression* can involve only literals of arithmetic types (2.13, 3.9.1), enumerators, **non-volatile
> const variables** or static data members **of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions** (8.5),

Meaning all of the const variables `SIZE`, `SIZE2` and `E1` (as these have been initialized with constant expressions) are valid in integral constant-expression, and may thus be used as template arguments for non-type template parameters.